# Sequence diagram for simple login system

Tags: java, uml, sequence, diagram

I have a partially finished sequence diagram but it needs more detail. Once the user has been retrieved from the database how does the system decide whether to accept or reject a login. I mean how do I implement it to my sequence diagram:

[image]

Comment: You need to tell what your issue is in detail. Just asking to complete it is by far too broad.

Answer (score 0):

The type of login your diagram represents is form-based authentication. Breaking it down into steps (no diagram):

1. User enters credentials (username, password) over a https connection.
2. If both credentials have been entered, for example a valid email address for the username and a password (anything) then:

   a. On the server, hash the password from step (1) with whatever algorithm you're using (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function); don't use md5 any more, there are several reasons it's no longer a good candidate such as hash collision and speed issues). Also see [here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

   b. On the server, get the row corresponding with the user you want to validate.

   If the row is present:

   - compare the hash you got in (2a) with what's in the database.

     - If it matches, handle the successful login; most likely you'll want to put a `Principal` object in the session to identify the logged in user. If you're keeping track of unsuccessful login accounts, zero this number (login was successful).
     - If it doesn't match (incorrect password for specified user)

       - return a failure with a generic message (don't give a potential attacker more information than necessary).
       - Here, if you're also keeping track of failed login attempts, increment the number and if it exceeds the maximum allowed consecutive failures, block the account.
       - Optional: send an email to the registered user informing them of a failed login attempt.

   Else

   - the row is not present; no user exists with that user name. Return a failure with a generic message.
3. Else (from 2--negative: both credentials have not been entered)

   a. Return a generic validation error (enter both username and password). Don't send anything to the server.

Note: If you're doing it with Java, do not use a `String` to store the password object as it is immutable. Store it in a `char[]` array that you can clear as soon as the password is no longer needed.